# VisualSVN Server

Tags: git, svn

I just want to clone a svn repo with this command:

```
git svn clone https://svn/repo/here/trunk
```

It asks me to type a Password for  but I have never set a password.
I read that I should look in the files in this directory:

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.simple
```

But this directory is empty.

And this is what I get:

```
$ git svn clone <url>
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/<user>/Desktop/git0/trunk/.git/
Authentication realm: <https://eps-svn:443> VisualSVN Server
Authentication realm: <https://eps-svn:443> VisualSVN Server
Authentication realm: <https://eps-svn:443> VisualSVN Server
Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL <url>: No more credentials or we tried too many times.
Authentication failed at C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/share/perl5/Git/SVN.pm line 148.
```

None of the suggestions in the other topics worked

Comment: please add error's pictures. Most likely, .net framework versions (that your solutions used) have not been installed

Answer (score 0):

- Right click the project/solution
- Re-target